# Inserting a CSS Rule with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I'm having trouble inserting a new CSS rule with Javascript in order to adjust the width of a display block with a fixed position to the width of the window. Could someone explain why this isn't working? Here's the jsfiddle for the HTML, CSS, and Javascript (along with a bit of jQuery) involved: http://jsfiddle.net/b9knL/ and this is the Javascript in question:

```
$(function () {
                function change_header(){ 
                     var sheets = document.styleSheets;
                     var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
                     var mywidth = $(window).width();
                     var selector = "header{ width: "+mywidth+"; }";
                     sheet.insertRule(selector, index);
                }
                change_header();

                $(window).resize(function() {
                        change_header();
                });
});
```

Comment: The scroll event happens a few hundred times when you scroll down a page, and you're inserting a new Rule every time, you're sure you've added enough of those ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a filler from an old function that I was using to make the header fixed, I will be changing that to a jQuery function that enables itself whenever the window size is changed.

Comment: index is undefined - add var index=0; to fix. also specify px for width. var selector = "header { width: "+mywidth_+"px; }";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is `position:fixed` just add `width:100%` to the css rule and it will auto adjust on its own..

```
header{
    background-color: #005e00;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 500;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;
}
```

no need for scripting..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/b9knL/2/

Comment: Well that was a much simpler answer than I expected! Thank you!